# vba to Retrieve href inside a div

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to retrieve the email address in a webpage, which has this html:

```html
 <div id="responseDiv" style="background-color:#EBECED;width: 450px;">
    <font style="letter-spacing: 0pt" size="3" face="Arial" 
    color="#336699">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
    <a href="mailto:recrutamento@sgp.pt?subject=Resposta Anuncio Net-                                   Empregos: TI SQL e VB.net" target="_blank">**recrutamento@sgp.pt**
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </a>
    </font></div>
```

so far I have tried the following that passes everything in that page except for the email address that I wanted:

```
Dim dataEle As Object, vElemento As String, tit as string
Set dataEle =Doc.getElementsByTagName("p") ' also tried with element "a"

For Each element In dataEle
  tit = element.getAttribute("href") 
  MsgBox (tit)
Next
```

Could it be, because element "a" is part of a Div? (responseDiv)

Answer (score 0):

I did test your code associated with your html div string with many emails as in the attached image to ensure you.

Just remember if that html div string is constants string, this solution will work just like you want:

```
Private Sub CmdRetrieveHrefInsideDiv_Click()
Dim test As String
Dim frstWrd As String
test = Text1.Value
frstWrd = Split(test, ":")(4)
Dim X As Integer
X = InStr(frstWrd, "?")
Dim MyEmail As String
MyEmail = Split(frstWrd, "?")(0)
MsgBox MyEmail
End Sub
```

I hope this can help you ^_^

[image]